# How to disable the test suite in MariaDB

Tags: makefile, mariadb

Today I compiled [MariaDB](http://mariadb.org) and noticed that about half of the installed files are just related to the test suite. Currently I rm usr/{mysql-test,sql-bench} from the install directory, but I'd like to disable the suite at configuration / compile time. Is there some option to disable compiling? configure takes no such option as far as I discovered.
That should decrease packaging time at least a little and it wouldn't use non-standard directories.

Answer (score 2):

Configure & compile for the test suite is minimal (a few seconds) so this should not be a big problem.

Having an option for 'make install' without test suite would probably not be a bad idea to make the install smaller. I will try to fix in MariaDB 5.5 that we have such an option.

What do you mean with 'non standard directories'?